# Maven build v IDE Build should both work selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, maven, selenium, webdriver

I have a Framework built using Java Selenium Webdriver, when I compile my tests via the IDE the test runs fine but when I use Maven it does not click the login button but no errors are reported. ? My confusion is that by looking at the errors it would seem both work fine. It is when then the window is viewed it can be seen the button is not clicked. Is this expected or has anyone seen this issue before? This Maven build also worked before so I can't understand why it does not now.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible scenario? My view is of course they both should work same

Comment: If it worked before, did you update the server browsers or the selenium library ?

Comment: I've changed both. I can't remember what they were originally. Is there a doc which states which version and firerfox should be used together?

Comment: I changed the browser version to FF 38 and selenium webdriver 38 and it is working.